# What's the easist way to push an application to your android-device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and Nexus One as my android-device.

And another question.

My android doesnt update automatically to 3.2 version (current version)..it says that it is up to date..and that it is updated..what do i do?

Comment: the question on android-version should a) be another question b) not be published on SO ... there are other platforms for such questions!

Comment: 3.2 isn't for phones, that's why your phone says its up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, choose "Run | Run Configurations ..." . In the Run Configurations dialog, select the target page, and select Manual. Then connect your Android, with USB debugging enabled (it doesn't matter if it is also a disk drive).

Now when you click Run, the Android Device Chooser dialog will appear, with your Android as a choice. If an emulator is running, it will also be a choice.

If your hardware Android does not appear, you must be missing the USB drivers. You have to get those from the specific manufacturer.

I don't see a way to make the hardware Android the default choice, which is annoying.

Comment: I am able to conenct the phone to the drive..i can open the android drive with all its folders inside..but i think that i am missing a drive..so I am updated my eclipse right now (I followed the instructions that you described already

Comment: The Android SD card will appear as a Windows drive without any new USB drivers. However the USB debugging access requires new USB drivers. They are not in Eclipse; they are provided by your phone manufacturer. For my HTC Desire, I had to install HTC Sync from the HTC website.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question is a user question, for which you should see [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/.). But no Nexus One currently runs anything later than 2.3.x.

Comment: hmm..why is that...i cant get 3.2...:(

Answer (score 1):

On your android-device, Go to "Settings" -> "Application settings" -> "Development"
turn on "USB Debugging"

Run from eclipse, choose your phone from devices as opposed to an emulator, and it'll install your app.

reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: Where is the option of choose from your device instead of emulator?

Comment: it'll show up as an option, if your device has USB debugging enabled and is connected to your computer via USB cable when you choose Run.

Comment: I have the android connected and I changed the settings in the application..to turn usb debugging and allow installation of uknown devices..still the emulator pops up instead

Comment: forgot 1 step --  Declare your application as "debuggable" in your Android Manifest.

In Eclipse, you can do this from the Application tab when viewing the Manifest (on the right side, set Debuggable to true). Otherwise, in the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable="true" to the <application> element.

Comment: It went to the debug configurations and clicked..manually decide..then the options popped up..but it doesnt identify my device..so I am updated my emulator now....It also says that the target is available for 3.0..should I reduce my api level to 2.3.x

Comment: @kharles let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2315/discussion-between-dmitry-makovetskiyd-and-kharles)

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone to the computer and select the play button in Eclipse.

Comment: that never worked for me ... do you need any more options to be set on your android-device?

Comment: On Windows, you'll need the Google Android drivers (available from the developer site). On Linux you'll need the proper udev rules, or adb running as root. On Mac OS, it should just work.